# Uploading a video through youtube official library through php cli request but resulting in (Undefined Index: HTTP_HOST). Any idea to solve this?

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm getting an error of **Undefined Index: HTTP_HOST** while trying to send a video to Youtube API using the Official Youtube Google API PHP Library.

The request is happening under laravel scheduler to run cli request to do the task.

I have tried and find a way of adding Host Header Parameter to the request but couldn't get it done.

I also tried specifying the `rootUrl` param when iniatializing the Google Youtube Service like so;

`$service = new Google`*`Service`*`Youtube($client, 'https://youtube.googleapi.com');`

What can I do to solve this error?

Comment: please edit your question and include [example] there is not enough code here to help debug your issue.

Comment: To create a service you should be using **$service = new Youtube($client);**